# Trying to hide the add fee text if criteria is met in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, fee

I have a code that i found here on stackoverflow for WooCommerce that allows to add an extra fee if the order is under a set value.

(in this example i have the value ten, everything under that value will add the difference as an procesing tax)

I would like to hide the text in the order page if the the sum of the order is over that set value.

Here is the code:

```php
function woo_add_cart_fee() {

    global $woocommerce;

    $subt = $woocommerce->cart->subtotal;

    if ($subt < 10 ) { 
        $surcharge = 10 - $subt;
    } else { 
        $surcharge = 0;
    }   

    $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( __('Procesing tax for under 10 dolars', 'woocommerce'), $surcharge );

}

add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'woo_add_cart_fee' );
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

global `$woocommerce` is not necessary because you have access to `$cart`.

Adding the fee can be included in the if condition

```php
function woo_add_cart_fee( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    // Get subtotal
    $subt = $cart->get_subtotal();

    // Below
    if ($subt < 10 ) {
        $surcharge = 10 - $subt;

        $cart->add_fee( __( 'Procesing tax for under 10 dolars', 'woocommerce' ), $surcharge );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'woo_add_cart_fee', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: Wow, that's great, not only does the text disappear but the fee is calculated before taxes. Thanks you a lot!

Comment: I just seen a bug in the code, I have a shipping fee for orders under the value of 50 and free for orders over 50, but with this code the free shipping doesnt work anymore

Comment: How was this determined? via custom code or via WooCommerce settings or an extra plugin?

Comment: I dont why it did that for a few orders, then i did nothing and it worked correctly. Thank you again!